# Are there problems that cannot be solved in polynomial space?

Tags: theory, space-complexity

There are problems that can't be solved in polynomial time, but are there problems that can't be solved using polynomial space?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may be interested in this question on the related Computer Science site: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30346/how-can-an-algorithm-have-exponential-space-complexity-but-polynomial-time-compl

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE#Relation_among_other_classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the extreme case, there are problems like the halting problem that are undecidable, so they can't be solved in *any* amount of space. On a more practical level, there's the [space hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) which can be used to construct a problem that can be solved in space O(2<sup>n</sup>) but not space o(2<sup>n</sup>), ruling out polynomial-space solutions.